# Bounds on the zeros of a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm stuck on the following problem:

> Let $p(z) = z^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+a_0$ be a polynomial of degree $n$, and let $A = \max\{|a_i|: 0\leq i \leq n-1\}$. Show that $p(z)$ has $n$ roots (counted with multiplicity) in the disk $|z|<A+1$.

I have attempted (but failed) to show that $|p(z)|>0$ on $|z|\geq A+1$. Then I would be done by the fundamental theorem of Algebra.

I wonder whether this is just a slick application of Rouche's theorem.

There is a proof on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra#Bounds_on_the_zeros_of_a_polynomial) which uses Holder's inequality, which I haven't seen yet.

Could anyone provide some hints for a proof which does not use this inequality? Am I even on the right track?

Comment: It looks to me like the Wikipedia page is dealing with a more general result; here the only Holder you need is the trivial $|\sum b_j a_j|\le (\max |a_j|)\sum|b_j|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the triangle inequality is needed, not even Rouché's theorem. First note that we can assume that $A>0$, because the statement surely holds for the polynomial $p(z) = z^n$.

Now assume that $p(z) = 0$.

**Case 1:** $|z| \le 1$. Then $|z| \le 1 < 1+A$.

**Case 2:** Then
$$
 |z^n| \le |a_{n-1}| |z|^{n-1} + \cdots + |a_1||z|+ |a_0| + \le A (|z|^{n-1} + \cdots + |z|+1) = A \frac{|z|^n-1}{|z|-1} 
$$
and it follows that
$$
 |z|-1 \le A \frac{|z|^n-1}{|z|^n} < A \, .
$$

This shows that $|z| < A+1$ for all roots of $p$.